# Can I host WordPress on MySQL Community in a commercial environment

Tags: mysql, wordpress, open-source

This really a question about the post-acquistion licensing around MySQL.

My company, which is a commercial software and services company, is planning on hosting a blog site on our domain for marketing purposes.  Our first choice is WordPress which recommends a MySQL backend.  My question for you is, as a commercial company, can we host our own instance of WordPress backed by MySQL Community Edition which is GPL licensed.  Here are some points which may clarify the situation...

1. We are a commercial company.
2. The blogs will be provided for free and we will gain no direct revenue from them.
3. We will be hosting the WordPress/MySQL instance directly on our site, rather than simply subscribing to a hosted service.
4. We have no plans to modify either the WordPress or MySQL code and plan to just use both out of the box.

Moderators, please feel free to move this question to any forum that you feel would be more appropriate.

Thanks in advance for any help,
Jeremy

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MySQL website:

"OEMs, ISVs and VARs can purchase commercial licenses."

So as long as you are not using it for your ISV endeavors you are free to use the community edition. However, it is best to reach out to the MySQL licensing team to get the most reputable answer: http://forums.mysql.com/list.php?4